# Make netty server on localhost accesable over internet

Tags: windows, server, localhost, netty, jooby

I have developed a Jooby-Application which is hosted on a netty server. I can access the application on localhost and tests were fine. Now I want to make the app accessable over internet and dont know what is the best way to reach this goal?

The complete application is hosted on a Windows Server, because it uses Excel. (Read/Write over Apache POI. For macros it has to be Windows) Should I try to connect the running netty-server with IIS or can I just forward the requests from outside to localhost? The last mentioned approach propably is a bad idea regarding security issues.

Comment: What do you mean by "it uses Excel"? Are you reading files in some .xls format?

Comment: yes, read/write over apache poi. and to execute macros it is neccessary that its hosted on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with reverse proxy over IIS. I had to install some features like Application Request Routing and URL Rewrite. Then I can start the jooby application (netty server) as usual on a specific port at localhost and set a reverse proxy to it.

Comment: How did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why being on a window is necessary, anyways, Netty is just a Java network programming framework, it can run on any platform where Java is installed.

You need to host a server, you can buy a VPS, install windows as OS, install Java, you can run your application as you like.

What I understand is you need to test it, for that you can use any port forwarding service like https://pagekite.net/support/intro/features/ to enable "world access" to localhost

Comment: Im sure, Windows is necessary because the Excel File has some Macros. And to execute these macros, I use VBScripts. Currently I have an Azure VM with Windows Server 2012. Is there no way to use the built in IIS and connect it to localhost? Dont know if Port Forwarding is the clean way.